# Join two columns as a date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, date

I am currently working with a report through Microsoft Query and I ran into this problem where I need to calculate the total amount of money for the past year.

The table looks like this:

```
Item Number | Month | Year | Amount |
...........PAST YEARS DATA...........
  12345     |   1   | 2019 |   10   |
  12345     |   2   | 2019 |   20   |
  12345     |   3   | 2019 |   15   |
  12345     |   4   | 2019 |   12   |
  12345     |   5   | 2019 |   11   |
  12345     |   6   | 2019 |   12   |
  12345     |   7   | 2019 |   12   |
  12345     |   8   | 2019 |   10   |
  12345     |   9   | 2019 |   10   |
  12345     |   10  | 2019 |   10   |
  12345     |   11  | 2019 |   10   |
  12345     |   12  | 2019 |   10   |
  12345     |   1   | 2020 |   10   |
  12345     |   2   | 2020 |   10   |
```

How would you calculate the total amount from 02-2019 to 02-2020 for the item number `12345`?

Comment: Do you want this thing in SQL or Excel?

Comment: Preferably in SQL! :)

Comment: @WhyMyCodeLong: then, please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are running SQL Server, you can recreate a `date` with `datefromparts()` and use it for filtering:

```
select sum(amount)
from mytable
where 
    itemnumber = 12345
    and datefromparts(year, month, 1) >= '20190201'
    and datefromparts(year, month, 1) < '20200301'
```

Comment: Is it possible to run this query dynamically? Instead of “20200301”, can I use getdate()?

Comment: You could use something like : `datefromparts(year, month, 1) between
       DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()`

Comment: Hi GMB, sorry for the delay response. The code works perfect. Thank you so much! Also thanks to @CR7SMS for the dynamics code.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this also

```
 SELECT sum(amount) as Amount
 FROM YEARDATA
 WHERE ( Month >=2 and year = '2019')
 or ( Month <=2 and year = '2020')
 and ItemNumber = '12345'
```